# Passing local image file path via object value to React prop not working?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, object, react-props

I have a file which contains an array of objects which have the values:

```
{
  id: .., 
  image: "require('./React.png')",
  name: ...,
  description:...,
  technology:..,
},
```

The `image` value contains the file path of the image file I would like to use as a string. The image is in the same directory as my component and object file.

When I destructure the props I am able to pass the `id`, `name`, `description`, and `technology` values to my component and they are displayed on the app fine. When I place the image prop inside of the image source attribute within the image tag the image is not displayed. (I am using JSX)

I've tried passing the image prop like: `{this.props.image}`/`{props.image}` to no avail.

The last P tag contains the same image prop I am trying to pass to my image source and it displays the route to my file as a string: `"require('./React.png')"`. So I know the prop is accessing the object value correctly. The image source attribute is just having a fit for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
const ProjectCard =({image, name, description, technolgy})=>{

  return(

    <div className='pa3 dib br2 ma2 bw2 shadow-5 grow tc'>

      <img src={{image}} style={{width:"60px", height:"60px"}} alt='logo'/>

      <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p>{description}</p>
        <p>{technolgy}</p>
        <p>{image}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you literally wrote a string with the content `"require('./React.png')"`, which means that will get passed down to your `<img>` component as `src` property. Since the string is not a valid URL, nothing will be displayed. Maybe your browser will display an error.

You have two options. Either you modify the string to be a correct URL by removing the `require` from the string; for example, you change it to `"./React.png"`. But then you need to configure your backend to actually serve this image for you.

Option two is to import that image in your javascript code into a variable and pass that to the `src` property of your `<img>` tag.

For example like this:

```
import reactImage from './React.png';

const ProjectCard =({name, description, technolgy})=> (
  <div className='pa3 dib br2 ma2 bw2 shadow-5 grow tc'>
    <img src={{reactImage}} style={{width:"60px", height:"60px"}} alt='logo'/>
    <div>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <p>{description}</p>
      <p>{technolgy}</p>
      <p>{image}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

But here is the catch. Since it looks like you are trying to display images dynamically, I would suggest you go with option 1 and NOT make images part of your bundle beforehand. Only do that with images that are a fixed part of your application, like icons or a logo.

Dynamic (content) images should be served from a web server.

Comment: You didn't describe how to do Option 1, how to " configure your backend to actually serve this image for you."

Comment: Yes because it completely depends on your kind of backend.

Answer (score -1):

Change value if the image in JSON to this:

```
{
  ...
  image: require('./React.png'),
  ...
}

<img style={{ width: 300 }} src={ props.image } />
```